# How to check whether a given date is DST date or not?

Tags: c#, dst

I have a date as string. There is no time info.
For eg. "20131031" ie) 31 oktober 2013.

I want to verify whether it is the date on which DST happens or not ?
w.r.t. WesternEurope.

ie) Does c# have an API, to say it is a DST date or not ?
I want simply a boolean as return, for the last sunday of October and last sunday of March.
which are the dates on which clocks are adjusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an API: TimeZone.GetDaylightChanges

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getdaylightchanges.aspx

You provide a year and it will return a DaylightTime object, which contains the start and end dates for daylight saving. You can then compare your date against those two to determine if its a DLS date or not.

Whilst this answer has been accepted, please see Matt Johnson's answer below for details why it's not the best answer and why the `TimeZoneInfo` class should be used instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19523173/7122

Comment: Please don't recommend the `TimeZone` class.

Comment: @MattJohnson, could you clarify that statement please?

Comment: Microsoft created the `TimeZoneInfo` class to replace `TimeZone`.  MSDN explicitly recommends to not use `TimeZone` any more.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @MattJohnson, Thanks, I didn't know that. I have updated my answer accordingly and up-voted you answer.

Answer (score 9):

Per [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeZone.aspx)

> **Important**
>
> Whenever possible, use the `TimeZoneInfo` class instead of the `TimeZone` class.

You should consider `TimeZone` deprecated.

Instead, you can check DST for the *local* time zone like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013,10,31);
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
bool isDST = tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(dt);
```

For a *specific* time zone, do this instead:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013,10,31);
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
bool isDST = tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(dt);
```

If you want to know when the daylight periods start and stop, you'll have to work through the transition rules from `tzi.GetAdjustmentRules()`.  That can get a bit complex though.  You would probably be better off using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `TimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime` method, it takes a `DateTime`:

```
public virtual bool IsDaylightSavingTime(
    DateTime time
)
```

So for example:

```
var tz = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
var is_dst = tz.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1f14e97%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Ah, that's even better than my answer. :)

Comment: IsDayLightSavingTime() is providing whether the specified date and time is within the daylight saving time period. But I wanted to know the start and end period of DST. Suggestion from David helps me.

Comment: @user1872757 You didn't ask that originally though.

Comment: Please don't recommend the `TimeZone` class.

Comment: @MattJohnson Ahh interesting I didn't see the notes, I haven't used it in a long time I just knew it existed.